# How to make full width of rows when have different count of columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I achieve result like in image below via CSS / HTML?

[image: table]

As you see first 2 rows have 2 columns, 3-4 rows have 3 columns, 5-6 rows should be full width. Problem is that I can't get different widths for different rows. Should I add class for each td and specify It's width manually? Maybe there is another way? I provided simplified sample, for reality there are over than 150 fields in table.

Here I've created [**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/pw1pe39j/) too see structure of table.

```
<table class="tbl">

<tr>
        <th>UserID </th>
        <th>FirstName </th>             
        <th>LastName </th>          
        <th>Picture </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>UserID</td>
        <td>FirstName</td>          
        <td>LastName</td>           
        <td>Picture</td>                
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Rank </th>              
        <th>RankApplied </th> 
        <th>DateApplied </th> 
        <th>DateAvailability </th>  
        <th>VesselsType </th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>               
        <td>RankApplied</td> 
        <td>DateAvailability</td>   
        <td>VesselsType</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DOB </th>               
        <th>POB </th>               
        <th>Nationality </th>       
        <th>English </th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DOB</td>                
        <td>POB</td>                
        <td>Nationality</td>        
        <td>English</td> 
    </tr>
    ....
```

Comment: That said...it doesn't look like *one* table...more like lots of mini-tables stacked one after the other.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't know If It's best choice to use tables at all in this case. I need to achieve structure like that in any way...

Comment: Well that's up to you...If it's tabular data (and it looks like it is) a table makes sense....but each set of rows could be their own table....and you can then lay it out how you want.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c2oozw6s/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with several techniques.
Personally I would choose [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) styling.

With `flex: 1 1 auto;` for grid-items they grow and shrink like you want.

I've put a quick example for this layout on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqpwgvoe/6/)

I use there `display: flex` even for the body but just to center the hole grid.

**Update**:
I updated the fiddle link for a more 'dynamic' layout.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but If text is so long, rows width not increasing, and if values (data) is different length than headers - width doesn't match. Updated JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mqpwgvoe/2/

Comment: yes. the grid-item style needs a `flex: 1 1 0;`value. And the grid-column style a `flex: 1 0 auto;` value to grow. I updated the fiddle link above. By the way the grid in this example is always 50% of the body, if you want to change that just change the flex value in the grid style or don't use flexbox at all (for that style) and use a fixed width for example...

Comment: Internet Explorer explicit needs a unit for the flex-basis value: `flex: 1 1 0px;`. I re-updated the fiddle link for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help!